# Translating Java 256 bit password based encryption to C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, hmac, pbkdf2

I need to implement an API in C# that'll encrypt secrets identically to the API written in java.

The Java code looks like this

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iteration, size);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "HmacSHA256");
```

My attempt on C# code looks like this

```
var secret = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
    password, salt, KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256, iteration, size);
```

When I compare the generated secrets, converted the to base 64, they're not the same. Their length are couple hundreds characters off as well.

What's missing from the C# code to generate the same secret as the Java API?

Comment: the java sample uses the base64 encoded SecretKey object `tmp` to create another secret key, have you tried to use the base64 encoded `secret` variable in your C# code as password to generate another secret key?

Comment: For `PBEKeySpec` in java the size is in units of bits, while for C# code it is in units of bytes. This, if you want AES-256, size should be 256 for Java but only 32 for C#.

Comment: 1. It is easier to see differences in hex vs Base64. 2. If the outputs are different length the size specification is probably or derivation information to the output. or one implementation is adding . 3. Add the outputs, in hex, to the question. 4. API authors like to make things mysterious by not specifying little things like bits or bytes and defaults. They like to show their superiority over mere users.

Comment: Changing the size worked! Thank you. I missed the bit/byte part.